# Gulp + Webpack tsloader removes require.js amd define moduleName annotation

Tags: typescript, webpack, build, gulp, requirejs

In Typescript project, compiled code should have the line:

```
 (function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
                        ... 
 define("moduleName", [], function () { ... } );
```

Using define from amd (Asynchronous Module Definition)

I transpile the ts files with gulp + webpack ts-loader and get

```
 define([], function () { ... } );
```

So I need to add moduleName by hand, is there a way to add it automatically (or simply not remove the name)?

I tried searching for it, ng-annotate or uglify mangle:false or amd-optimize but they didn't work.
I could probably hard-code it with gulp-replace but it's probably not a good idea.

In my webconfig I have:

```
library: 'moduleName',
libraryTarget: 'umd'
```

Anyone can help me with this small task?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, I need to add  `umdNamedDefine: true` for my webpack file.
See [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3119) and [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/)